# MatPaginator : change displaying properties

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project, in which I have a MatTable to display User data.

However, each row also has a "detailRow" that will unveil to give additional data only when clicking on the row. (expendedElement)

The problem is that the MatPaginator also takes into account the detailRow when doing the pagination. Example :

If I select "10" in the MatPaginator, it will only display 5 rows by page.

Since I do not want to change my dataSource, is there a way to manipulate the MatPaginator to make it work properly in my case ? (making him display twice the amount of rows asked off him)

Here's how my (basic) paginator looks like :

`<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]"></mat-paginator>`

And here's my dataSource :

`dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;
user = new User("name");
dataSource.push(user, { detailRow: true, user });`

Hope this is not too confused, thanks in advance for any ideas you may bring!

Comment: Can you share your code so it would be better to give answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something similar to the below code.

```
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator; 

// In the method you call on (page) use something like
      this.pageIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex// event.pageIndex;

    this.length = this.paginator.length;
    this.pageSize = this.paginator.pageSize * 2;
    var startIndex = this.pageSize * this.pageIndex;
    var endIndex = startIndex + this.pageSize;
    endIndex = (endIndex <= this.length) ? endIndex : this.length;
   /* Make sure you change back the value so that the value displayed is 5 when you have 10 rows displayed*/
    this.pageSize = this.pageSize / 2;
```